# Which git.exe should I reference?

Tags: windows, git, mingw

Git for Windows has installed four `git.exe` files.

They seem *slightly* different (comparing bytes).

Which should I use for other applications that want a reference to git.exe?

- `\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`
- `\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`
- `\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe`
- `\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The different version are each one for a different purpose.

- `\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`
  This is the actual git binary which is added to your path if you run it form any script etc.

  This entry found here in the git source script for windows:
  https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/69c134c3c2c46bce1083d5bd4596d26543ca5f0f/portable/release.sh
- `\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`
  This is the git which is run when you add installed and choose to add git to your `cmd` (windows path)

  This entry can be found here in the source :  `<File Id="GitExe" Source="cmd\\git.exe" />`
  https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/69c134c3c2c46bce1083d5bd4596d26543ca5f0f/msi/release.sh
- `\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe`
  This is the git-bash version which is used by the git-bash cygwin emulator

  It defined here in the wxs (installer file)
  https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/69c134c3c2c46bce1083d5bd4596d26543ca5f0f/msi/GitProduct.wxs

  ```
  <?if $(var.SixtyFourBit)=64 ?>
      <Directory Id='MingwFolder' Name='mingw64' />
  <?else?>
  ```
- `\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe`
  Thisone is also for the emulator and is being defined here:
  https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/69c134c3c2c46bce1083d5bd4596d26543ca5f0f/git-extra/git-prompt.sh

  `if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
  then
     GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
     COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
     ...`

Comment: For the `\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe` what do you mean when you say "add installed and choose to add git to your `cmd` (windows path)" I'm sill not understanding.  Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I have all those files in Windows. I don't use git bash, I use cmd.exe. If I type git --exec-path, it shows me the one in mingw64\libexec\git-core, Should I modify git to use the one in Program Files git/cmd/ or the one in git/bin/? And if so, how would I do that? And which one should I specify in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using from your windows command prompt you should be referring to the, `\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`

The ones under `mingw64` are used with the Git bash interface.