# What are the specific differences between these 4 git.exe under Windows OS?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

What are the specific differences between these 4 git.exe under Windows OS?

[image: Figure 1]
[CodeWizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40556175/9922806)'s answer didn't specify the difference between them.
[image: Figure 2]

Figure 2 is Intellij Idea import git version control, the strange thing is that all four git.exe work fine. why? thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

There are actually 2 distinct files: a wrapper file and the actual git executable.

The smaller files `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe` are wrappers that spawn the mingw64 version of git.

While both of them may work for IntelliJ, you're probably better of pointing to one of the wrappers since they are intended to setup the git environment when running git outside of the Git for Windows bash shell.

## Long Answer

Although there are 4 executable files, there are only 2 distinct executables in terms of unique file contents.

```
PS C:\Program Files\Git> Get-FileHash .\bin\git.exe,.\cmd\git.exe,.\mingw64\bin\git.exe,.\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA256          8984FB839A6A70DD84E644F91C81F191F3C9056BC7A1152669C608791F180468       C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
SHA256          8984FB839A6A70DD84E644F91C81F191F3C9056BC7A1152669C608791F180468       C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
SHA256          F3E755DCACAC1070160103CD716CEA728FFB101EC44EDF989AD8C5A467FF31DC       C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
SHA256          F3E755DCACAC1070160103CD716CEA728FFB101EC44EDF989AD8C5A467FF31DC       C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe
```

Of the 2 distinct executables, the mingw versions are meant to be used within the bash shell that comes with the Git for Windows distribution...

[image: git bash]

...while the other two versions are used from Windows shells (Powershell and cmd). These files are wrappers that setup the git environment for mingw git.exe and then spawn mingw git.exe.

[image: Powershell]

### Running Git from the Command Line

When you install Git for Windows, your `PATH` environment variable is updated to the contain the `Git\cmd` path, which has one of the copies of `git.exe`. On my machine, this path is `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`.

If you run that version of `git.exe` while [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is running, you will see that one of the first things it does is spawn a new process running `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe`.

[image: Process Monitor]

Comment: and why can Intellij Idea use any one of the files?

Comment: updated answer with more information about the differences between the git.exe versions.

Comment: thanks, but why Intellij Idea can only use the wrapper git, or just use the actual executable git ?   In addition, since the hash value is the same, why does git use 4 files instead of 2? Even using only one executable git file doesn't work? must use wrapper?

Comment: They are almost the same. The wrapper sets up some environmental options to run the actual git program. Depending on what git functionality IntelliJ uses, this may or may not be a problem. However, you're better off using the wrapper since it is specifically designed to configure the environment for the real git executable.

Comment: I don't know why there are 2 copies of each version of the file. I thought they may be hardlinks but I checked with fsutil and they are not.